# How do I access previous workouts recorded via Apple Watch?

Tags: apple-watch

I want to see my detailed stats about my previous run.

I tried searching for a manual - https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204523 - but I don't seem to find such option.

On this occasion I was running with Apple Watch only (no iPhone, no GPS) but if I have the outline I manually set the starting point.

But first things first - how do I access data from my previous workout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The historical data (other than the last summary data for each activity) is available in two places by default:

1. On the paired iPhone - you can use the activity app to review your workouts as well as going into health app to review data.
2. On the watch itself - you can look at today's workout(s) in the Activity app, but not go back in time as of Watch OS 2.0

Comment: Of course! **Activity app** on the iPhone... Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

There's 3rd-party apps that provide such functionality, but nothing made by Apple on the Apple Watch itself, probably due to simplicity.

Comment: Do you mind recommending such 3rd party apps? Digression: NSA springs to mind "let's store everything and analyse later" :) I wonder is there a reason why there is no way of viewing archived workouts? (me === monkey)